# How do I bind a WPF combo box to a different list when the dropdown is open?

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, binding

I have several combo boxes in a Scheduling module that all have dropdown lists based on an "Active" field.

```
public class Project
{
    public int ProjectID { get; set; }
    public int ProjectTitle { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
}

<ComboBox
    Name="ProjectComboBox"
    ItemsSource="{Binding AllProjects}"
    SelectedItem="{Binding Project, Mode=TwoWay}">
</ComboBox>
```

The calendar's editing form must always display legacy information in its combo boxes, even if a particular item in a combo list has been deactivated.  But if the drop-down is opened, it must only show those items in the list that are still active.

How would I accomplish this?

I have tried this, in the codebehind:

```
private void ProjectComboBox_DropDownOpened(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ProjectComboBox.SetBinding(ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty, "ActiveProjects");
}

private void ProjectComboBox_DropDownClosed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ProjectComboBox.SetBinding(ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty, "AllProjects");
}
```

Which displays the correct list in the dropdown, but de-selects the originally-selected Project.  If the user does not select a new project, the combo box needs to retain its original selection when the dropdown is closed.

Comment: So you loose the selection. Hmm.. let my think.. ;) ... If you notice the selection `ComboBox.SelectedItem` before resetting the `ComboBox.ItemsSource` in `DropDownOpend` event handler and set it after resetting the `ComboBox.ItemsSource` in `DropDownClosed` event handler, then you can also reach the goal. But the solution from ASh is preferable since there is no code behind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

instead of changing ItemsSource, hide inactive elements via Visibility binding:

```
<BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="boolToVisibility"/>

<ComboBox Name="ProjectComboBox" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding AllProjects}"
          DisplayMemberPath="ProjectTitle"
          SelectedItem="{Binding Project, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" 
                    Value="{Binding Active, Converter={StaticResource boolToVisibility}}"/>
        </Style>
    </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: I assume the converter should set visibility to "collapsed" for those items that are not active?

Comment: @RobertHarvey, .NET comes with BooleanToVisibilityConverter which does that

Answer (score 0):

This also works, and might provide better flexibility for those looking to do something similar:

```
<ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Active}" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```